# Deriving Feature Map formula for Inhomogeneous Polynomial Kernel

Tags: machine-learning, classification, neural-network, svm, feature-extraction

How do we derive/extrapolate the feature map for inhomogeneous polynomial kernels for degree $d$, define as $$K(x, x^\prime) = \bigg( (x \cdot x^\prime) + c\bigg)^d$$

I know we don't need to know a valid feature map to use the inhomogeneous polynomial kernels, I'm simply curious as to how one would derive/extrapolate it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x, y \in \mathbb R^N, \mathbf \alpha \equiv (\alpha_0, \dots, \alpha_N) \equiv (\alpha_0, \mathbf \alpha'_0), \; \mathbf z^\alpha \equiv z_0^{\alpha_0} \dots z_N^{\alpha_N}$ and ${d \choose \alpha}$ be the [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Alternate_expression). Then

$$\left(\left<\mathbf x, \mathbf y \right> + c\right)^d = \sum_{|\mathbf \alpha| = d} {d \choose \alpha} c^{\alpha_0} (\mathbf x \mathbf y)^{\mathbf \alpha'_0}$$

If you redistribute the coefficient ${d \choose \alpha} c^{\alpha_0}$ between $\Phi(\mathbf x)$ and $\Phi(\mathbf y)$, it follows that

$$\Phi(\mathbf z) = \left(\sqrt{ {d \choose \alpha} c^{\alpha_0}} \mathbf z^{\alpha'_0} \right)_{\forall |\mathbf \alpha| = d}$$

### References

- [A Tutorial on Support Vector Machines for Pattern Recognition](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/67119/svmtutorial.pdf) (cf. *6.1. The VC Dimension for Polynomial Kernels*)
- [Data Mining and Analysis: Fundamental Concepts and Algorithms](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~stewart/lec23-post/kernels.pdf), Ch.5, pp 149-151.